# How do I allow Ubuntu to use more space on my computer?

Tags: wubi

Ubuntu currently won't use more than 4GiBs on my computer, but I need more space. My computer can hold much more than 4GiBs. How do I allow Ubuntu to use more? Please give step-by-step instructions in plain English.

#### Update:

I'm referring to my Ubuntu operating system. I installed it using Wubi through Microsoft Windows. I deleted Wubi from my Windows desktop after installation. All I want is to expand my Ubuntu operating system. I plan to gradually transition from Windows to Ubuntu and so I'll need to transfer more files and programs from Windows to Ubuntu in the future.

Right now, I already need more GiBs for Ubuntu. I can barely use Ubuntu right now because there's almost no space left. I simply want Ubuntu to use what space I need it to use. People, please quit complicating this issue and inform me how to make Ubuntu use more space.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "space".

Comment: Ubuntu release?

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Did you install it by booting from an Ubuntu install CD/DVD or USB flash drive and clicking `Install Ubuntu`, or did you install it while in Windows, with the Windows installer (Wubi). Please also open a Terminal (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`), run `df -h`, and provide the output. You can provide this and other requested information by **editing your question** to include it.

Comment: @EliahKagan: almost certainly Wubi since that is the default (min) size of a Wubi install ;)

Comment: and see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk on how to do it

Comment: did you create onother partition(sized 4 gigs) or install it with wubi from windows?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are referring to RAM. Your system does not use more than 4GB because you have installed a 32bit system, but don't worry, do this:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-pae
```

then reboot.
Now you can check with `free` how much RAM is used by your system.